# Flutter-My provider doesn't seem to notify its listeners after calling update method

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have a CupertinoTabView with 3 tabs. My problem is related to the first one, which displays some delivery information. We can update the delivery status by clicking update button of each item in the list, which will take us to another screen called UpdateDeliveryStatusScreen with Navigator.push(). After the update request is sent and response is returned, we go back to our list of deliveries with Navigator.pop(). I am using Provider for state management. However, when I go back to the list of deliveries, the status still isn't updated even though everything worked correctly and the list of deliveries in the provider is updated. Here are my codes:

MainScreen:

```
...
CupertinoTabScaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
          tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
            onTap: onTabTapped,
            items: const [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                label: 'Home',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_month),
                label: 'Availability',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                label: 'Profile',
              ),
            ],
          ),
          tabBuilder: (context, index) {
            var currentWidget;
            if (index == 0) {
              currentWidget = CupertinoTabView(
                navigatorKey: firstTabNavKey,
                builder: (BuildContext context) => Consumer<DeliveryProvider>(
                  builder: (_, value, child) => DeliveryWidget(),
                ),
              );
            } 
...
```

DeliveryWidget:

```
class DeliveryWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  /* final List<Delivery> deliveries;
  HomeWidget({required this.deliveries}); */
  @override
  State<DeliveryWidget> createState() => _DeliveryWidgetState();
}

class _DeliveryWidgetState extends State<DeliveryWidget> {
  List<Item> _data = [];

  Future<void> initData() async {
    final deliveryProvider =
        Provider.of<DeliveryProvider>(context, listen: false);
    await deliveryProvider.getDeliveries(context);
    final deliveries = deliveryProvider.deliveries;
    deliveries.forEach((element) {
      _data.add(generateItem(element));
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initData();
  }

  Color? getStatusColor(String status) {
    Color? color;
    if (status == 'Received') {
      color = Colors.green;
    } else if (status == 'Dispatched') {
      color = Colors.yellow;
    } else if (status == 'In Transit') {
      color = Colors.orange;
    } else if (status == 'Delivered') {
      color = Colors.red;
    }
    return color;
  }

  String getButtonText(String status) {
    String text = '';
    if (status == 'In Transit') {
      text = 'pin code';
    } else {
      text = 'update';
    }
    return text;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: _data.isNotEmpty
          ? _buildPanel()
          : const Center(
              child: Text('No data found'),
            ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPanel() {
    var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return ExpansionPanelList(
      expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
        setState(() {
          _data[index].isExpanded = !isExpanded;
        });
      },
      children: _data.map<ExpansionPanel>((Item item) {
        return ExpansionPanel(
          headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
            return ListTile(
              leading: FittedBox(
                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                child: Text(
                  item.delivery.orderNr,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 10,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.red),
                ),
              ),
              title: FittedBox(
                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                child: Text(
                    'from: ${item.delivery.origin}\nto: ${item.delivery.destination}'),
              ),
              trailing: SizedBox(
                width: 100,
                child: Row(children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 12,
                    height: 12,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        color: getStatusColor(item.delivery.status)),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  ),
                  Text(item.delivery.status)
                ]),
              ),
            );
          },
          body: ListTile(
            leading: SizedBox(
              width: width * 0.3,
              child: Text(
                'Weight: ${item.delivery.weight} kg',
              ),
            ),
            title:
                SizedBox(width: width * 0.4, child: Text(item.delivery.type)),
            subtitle: SizedBox(
                width: width * 0.4,
                child: Text('HxWxD: ${item.delivery.dimensions}')),
            trailing: SizedBox(
                width: width * 0.2,
                child: FittedBox(
                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          IconButton(
                              onPressed: () => null, icon: Icon(Icons.comment)),
                          IconButton(
                              onPressed: () => null, icon: Icon(Icons.person))
                        ],
                      ),
                      CupertinoButton(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => UpdateDeliveryStatusScreen(),
                            settings: RouteSettings(
                              arguments: {'delivery': item.delivery.toJson()},
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          getButtonText(item.delivery.status),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )),
          ),
          isExpanded: item.isExpanded,
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}

class Item extends ChangeNotifier {
  Delivery delivery;
  bool isExpanded;

  Item({required this.delivery, this.isExpanded = false});
}

Item generateItem(Delivery delivery) {
  return Item(delivery: delivery);
}
```

UpdateDeliveryScreen (just the updating part):

```
await DeliveryService.updateDeliveryStatus(body, delivery.id)
                      .then((Delivery newDelivery) {
                    final prov =
                        Provider.of<DeliveryProvider>(context, listen: false);
                    prov.updateDelivery(newDelivery);
                    prov.deliveries.forEach((element) {
                      print(element.status);
                    });
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  });
```

DeliveryProvider:

```
class DeliveryProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Delivery> deliveries = [];

  Future<void> getDeliveries(context) async {
    deliveries = await DeliveryService.getDeliveries();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void updateDelivery(Delivery delivery) {
    deliveries[deliveries.indexWhere((a) => a.id == delivery.id)] = delivery;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Sorry for the huge amount of code. I tried to make it as short as possible. Please let me know if you need anything else. Thanks in advance.

p.s. the status is updated in backend successfully, just not the UI.

Comment: Perhaps you could try adding a listener to the value of the provider in the `initState` method and then `setState` on any listened changes. This could then update you UI to reflect the changes? Just a guess!

Comment: `setState` on any listened change should be done with the `notifyListeners()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
Navigator.push(...).then((value)=> setState((){}));
```

This way the UI gets updated by the pop of the other screen.

Comment: Thank you so much, I fixed it with a small alteration. Instead of `setState((){})` , I called my `initData()` function which populates the data of the page. I don't know if it's a right approach to fetch all the data from the beginning every time there is an update on an item, but it definitely saved the day!